# Is it possible to run WPF Application on browser?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am new to WPF. I wanted to know that is it possible to run a wpf application on a browser or do i have to create a different WPF Browser application ?

Comment: yes u have to create separate application, otherwise there will be no difference in desktop and web application. Programmers are waiting for this salvation

Comment: Sounds like you're actually thinking of Silverlight which runs in the browser, and has a lot of similarities with WPF.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create a [WPF Browser Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx)

This is a separate project type - the [WPF Browser Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628663.aspx) as you have correctly identified.

You deploy the application to a web server so that it can be downloaded and run.

This only works in the desktop version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Note: XBAP appears to be depreciated in Microsoft Edge, related topics:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77512575-ea03-41b7-a2c2-682a1dd1f7ad/does-windows-10-edge-support-xbap?forum=win10itproapps , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880760/should-i-still-use-silverlight-xbap?rq=1

Comment: @jrh - which didn't exist in 2012 when I wrote this answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I came upon this question looking for the state of XBAP on various browsers these days; I wasn't sure if XBAP worked on Chrome, though. Has it been depreciated because it depends on NPAPI?

Comment: @jrh - I would have thought that it was an IE specific thing rather than NPAPI.

Comment: This post (2014) seems to indicate at one point XBAP was supported by Chrome and Firefox, through an (NPAPI) extension, http://www.essentialobjects.com/forum/postst8594_XBAP-in-EOWebBrowser.aspx , I'm not sure if there's a newer non-NPAPI extension that still works with those browsers, though. Can somebody confirm that XBAP is definitely not working / will be depreciated in Chrome and FF? I'm not really up to date with web technologies yet.