# Is it possible to display .net control content in Webbrowser

Tags: c#, html

Today I was confronted with the following problem. We do have a WPF control which displays dynamic content inside a closed system. Is it possible to display this control inside Chrome on a remote machine? We would like to display the content of this control on a remote machine with bidirectional communication. Any idea where to start? Just capturing a screenshot and transmitting this is not an option. Buttons in the control should also work on the remote machine.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run WPF Application on browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119683/is-it-possible-to-run-wpf-application-on-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  This is only possible in Internet Explorer.  Even on Edge you cannot do this.  With modern browsers, you can just forget about it.  Even Silverlight is no longer working with Chrome.

You need to re-implement this controller is JS / HTML.